# HP Probook 650 display issue on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: drivers, graphics, display, screen, hp

I have recently installed Ubuntu 18.04 on my HP Probook which has builtin Intel graphics card.

At start,it works fine but after some time, my screen gets pixelated, when I restart,it it works fine but again after some time, it gets pixelated.
Below is my graphics card info:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
    Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller
    Kernel driver in use: i915
    Kernel modules: i915
```

uname -a output:

```
Linux Kamran 5.0.0-37-generic #40~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Thu Nov 14 12:06:39 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: This looks like a hardware issue.

Comment: Might be, but it is working fine on windows.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA|3D|Display'` terminal command.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I added the output

Comment: Please also add output of `uname -a`.

Comment: All looks good. That must be some bug. Report it to Launchpad.

Comment: Added the output as well.

Comment: Well but how to find the bug?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug